# Extract value in Swift switch

Tags: swift, swift3, pattern-matching

Is it possible in Swift to pattern match and extract the initial value (now cast) at the same time?

For example, if I had these enums:

```
enum Inner {
    case a(Int)
    case b(Int)
}

enum Outer {
    case one
    case two(Inner)
}
```

and I wanted to match `Outer.two(Inner.a(1))` and have have a variable cast to that at the same time

```
let value: Any // Could be anything :|

switch value {
case let a as Outer.two(Inner.a(1)):
     // Do something which needs `a`
default"
    // Do some other things
}
```

Obviously, that doesn't work because `as` only casts to types.

I've also tried

```
case Outer.two(let a) where a == Inner.a(1):
case let Outer.two(.a(1)) = a: // i.e. the syntax in "guard case let ..."
```

which don't work. (NB The first would work, but implementing `==` isn't an option for me, annoyingly)

FYI: Scala lets you do it with the `@` operator, something like this:

```
case a @ Outer.two(Inner.a(1)):
```

Is there a syntax which can do this, or do I need to rethink how I'm solving my problem?

Comment: Why can't you match with `case Outer.two(Inner.a(1)):` ? Then you know that `a == Inner.a(1)` .

Comment: @MartinR I'd know, but the compiler wouldn't - I need to pass `a` around after it's matched.

Comment: Why can't you assign `let a = Inner.a(1)` if the case has matched?

Comment: @MartinR In this example I could, in my real life situation it's a bit tricker (not impossible, but it would make the code quite ugly).

Comment: @MartinR (Can you add your suggestion as an answer - it's the cleanest I've got so far!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an equivalent pattern to 
`case a @ Outer.two(Inner.a(1)):` in Swift. Here is a possible
workaround:

```
switch value {
case Outer.two(Inner.a(1)):
    let a = Inner.a(1)
    // Do something which needs `a`
default:
    // Do some other things
}
```